# What is the best book to learn statistics?

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request

Right now I'm taking a 3 part course on probability and statistics using Schverish & Degroot Probability and Statistics and it is just not helpful. For the first part, which was on Probability, I used a First Course in Probability by Sheldon Ross which was extremely helpful unfortunately it doesn't have much statistics. So is there a similar textbook that is focused on statistics?

Answer (score 2):

Sheldon Ross has a book on Introductory Statistics.  I like Rice's book, too.

Answer (score 2):

I always love a text book that contains a large number of worked examples and detailed solutions, a problem-solving approach book because I'm a type of student 'learn best by doing'. So, my recommendation statistics book is **Schaum's Outlines Series: Probability and Statistics** by Murray R. Spiegel, John J. Schiller, and R. Alu Srinivasan. Also, **Probability & Statistics for Engineers & Scientists** by Ronald E. Walpole, Raymond H. Myers, Sharon L. Myers, and Keying Ye.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$